# Load Reference Properties Which are Defined with Foreign Key Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I've got a complex view that returns an Entity with multiple reference properties.
When I'm displaying the object directly from the database, I can use the explicit loading to get the reference properties loaded before passing the model along to the View.

When the ModelState is invalid, I want to pass along the version of the object that the user has sent me, (so I can maintain the values that the user changed), and show the user the validation errors. However, in order for the view to load, I need all of the Reference and Navigation properties to load.

This doesn't work:

```
_db.Entry(workOrder).Reference(a => a.RecordTracker).Load();
```

after running this, `workOrder.RecordTracker` is still null.

But this clunky thing does work:

```
workOrder.RecordTracker = _db.RecordTrackers.Find(((WorkOrder)(_db.Entry(workOrder).GetDatabaseValues().ToObject())).RecordTrackerID);
```

I'm sure I'm missing something.

What's REALLY weird is that is works properly with these properties:

```
_db.Entry(workOrder).Reference(a => a.DocumentNumber).Load();
_db.Entry(workOrder).Reference(a => a.Vendor).Load();
_db.Entry(workOrder).Reference(a => a.CreatedFromDocument).Load();
```

One difference between `RecordTracker` and these classes are that they have a reference back to the `WorkOrder` defined, and `RecordTracker` is linked to in one direction, from the `WorkOrder`.

Another difference between the classes is that in `Document` (base class for WorkOrder), I define the `RecordTrackerID` like this:

```
    [ForeignKey("RecordTracker")]
    public int RecordTrackerID { get; set; }
```

Whereas the `DocumentNumber` is defined in the fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasRequired(d => d.DocumentNumber).WithRequiredPrincipal(d => d.Document).Map(m => m.MapKey("DocumentID")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I do need access to the `RecordTrackerID` field in the `Document` types.

I changed the code to define the relationship in the fluent API, and the load worked. I lose access to `RecordTrackerID` on the document class.

**So: Is there a way to load related Reference Properties when the relationship is defined in the class using Foreign Key Attributes rather than through the Fluent API in the model builder?**

Alternately, having access to the "MapKey" as a field would work as well.

Comment: Do you need to be accessing your entity via `_db.Entry(workOrder)` for some structural reason? Normally this would be done by something like `_db.WorkOrders.Include(x => x.RecordTracker).Single(x => x.Id == wordOrder.Id)` to get the whole workorder entity with the related complex child entity. or `_db.RecordTrackers.Single(x => x.WorkOrderId == workOrder.Id)` if you only want the `RecordTracker` entity

Comment: It is a scenario where I am getting the workOrder from the Request.Form in an httpPost. I am maintaining the form version, and just getting some state of reference properties from the database. This is because I don't want to have all the IDs of my reference properties as hidden fields in the form just so I can avoid this.

Comment: The problem is not whether you use fluent config or data annotations. Looks like this is one-to-one relationship, and EF does not support explicit FK property for such relationship (no `HasForegnKey` method), so `ForeignKey` annotation is simply ignored.

Comment: Are you saying my DB Model will be exactly the same if I take that off?